# Importing a "Dictionary" into an iOS game

Tags: ios, ios7

I am creating a game that needs a dictionary built in. When the user clicks a button, it checks to see if the word that they submitted is a word in the dictionary.

However, I have no idea of going about this. I know there are a whole bunch of ways storing data such as Foundation, Core Data, SQLite, etc...

What would be the best option?

And oh, It has to be 100% completely offline!

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Generally you'd use a SQLite database for this, assuming the list is over, say, 10,000 values.

Comment: I think using a NSArray would be more useful than a dictionary in this case.

Comment: You'll need to profile the various options yourself, but I'd imagine core data is the way to go.

Comment: @68cherries - If the check is only for the presence of the word a dictionary makes more sense than an array, and a set makes more sense than either.

Comment: Also, maybe look into [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: @Kevin - I was thinking punched cards.

Answer (score 1):

OK, a look at the options:

Assumptions:  You have a list of words.  The list is of unknown size.  Presumably the words are of "normal" length, varying from one character to maybe 50 in length, and distributed more or less normally for a European language.

Options:

1. NSArray, presumably loaded from a plist.
2. NSDictionary, presumably loaded from a plist.
3. NSSet.  NSSet does not have methods to restore directly from a plist, so one would probably have to read an NSArray from a plist, then create the NSSet from the array, a relatively simple step.
4. Trie (radix tree).  One would have to construct this using custom code, though presumably not much difference in efficiency than creating a NSSet.
5. SQLite.  One would presumably create the DB file offline and add it to the bundle.  On first execution of the app it would be copied to read/write storage and from then on could be accessed in place.
6. Core Data.  I'm not that familiar with Core Data since our team can't use it (since all our data must be encrypted).  But I understand that it's based on SQLite.  My understanding, though, is that the DB would have to be "built" on first install, vs being simply loaded as with SQLite.

Analysis:

1. There's not much to recommend using an NSArray.  One would have to either search it linearly or arrange for it to be sorted and use a "homespun" binary search.  No peformance advantage, and added code to write and to break.
2. Using an NSDictionary would be efficient, and would make sense if definitions or other data is to be stored with each word.  If the intent is to only test for the presence or absence of a word, however, the "value" part of the key/value pairs would go unused.
3. An NSSet, other than the slight glitch required to initialize it, is the most efficient way to represent a list of words where only "membership" (presence/absence) needs to be tested.  Not a good way to deal with the situation where other data must be stored with the word.
4. I'm not sure I see any point in using a trie.  It is, on average, not significantly more efficient in time or space than the NSSet (or NSDictionary, if "value" data is needed), but it's more code to write and more code to break.
   (Using a trie *does* have an advantage if you want to do "prompting", where if part of a word is typed you display the list of possible "completions", similar to what Google does.  The trie is the most natural data structure for this specific function.)
5. If the list of words is fairly large (over 10K, maybe, and certainly if over 100K) then using an external DB such as SQLite is probably the best bet.  Lookup is not as fast as an NSSet, but one would not likely notice the difference, once the first-time processing is done no special effort is required on app start, and the word list does not occupy RAM while the app is executing.  Whether or not one wants additional data with the word would be of little consequence.  (One would want to be sure to describe an index over the word column in the word table, for speed.)
6. As I said, I'm not very familiar with Core Data, but I understand it to be built on top of SQLite.  However, I don't think you can just install a Core Data DB file like you can a SQLite file, so some significant amount of first-time processing would be required.  I'm also not sure if Core Data allows you to specify an index to be over the word column.

So I would say NSSet for a "small" list, SQLite for a "large" list.

Comment: If I were to use a set, how would I go about reading from a text file line by line and inserting each word into the set at the same time?

Comment: @user3598042 - I'd suggest reading from a plist into an NSArray and then creating the set from the array.  Very straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside the [Instapaper](http://instapaper.com) app bundle, you will find a 17.2 MB file called `wiktionary.db`. It looks like they are storing a simplified dump of Wiktionary as a read-only SQLite database. If you just need to know if the word is in the dictionary, and not its definition, you could get the file size way below what Instapaper has.